# NLP: wit.ai. How to use confidence score?

Tags: nlp

I've created an application on Facebook's [wit.ai](http://wit.ai). In my application, I have a single intent with the following phases:

```
Hello
Hi bud
Hi
Hey there
Hey
Hey bud !! How's it going ?
Hey bud !! Hoss it going ?
```

Now if I try the easy phase `Hello`, I get a confidence score 0.535.

But now if I  try the phase `shut up`, I also get a confidence score 0.535.

**Question:** How does the Facebook wit.ai work? I don't understand why I would get the same confidence score in both cases.